# Any way to go directly to the "Enable Usb Debugging" page in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-context

Is there an Intent that goes directly to the "Enable USB Debugging" toggle or a way to request it to be enabled?

---Situation Explanation---

We have an application we use for testing on many phones at once and they all have developer mode enabled. However, usb debugging needs to be enabled when they're all reflashed.

We're aware of how to do this via ADB but our use case requires using a traditional in Android approach.

--- End Explanation

Is it possible to open a dialog allowing the user to go directly to the Usb Debugging option?

Similarly, is it possible to do this with developer mode?

Comment: Since USB debugging is hidden behind developer mode, and since developer mode needs to be enabled via the "tap 7 times to prove that you're a developer" stuff, I don't think there are direct `Intent` actions for these.

Comment: In regards to your last sentence, it *is* possible to programmatically open the dev mode settings (see my answer), but not to actually enable them. Not sure which you were asking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible I'm afraid.

[Here is a list of all Settings that can be opened with an Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#constants_1), note that USB debugging is not among them.

The closest you can get is opening up development settings (as the 2nd half of your question asked) with `ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS` ([more info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS)), which does the following:

> Activity Action: Show settings to allow configuration of application development-related settings.

Answer (score 5):

## Edit 1

`handleQsTileLongPressActionIfAny` was added in Android 12, so this only works in Android 12 and higher.

In the entire source for Android 11's Settings app there is no `SubSettingLauncher` with `WirelessDebuggingFragment.class` found, so an alternative solution is not possible.

## Preface

Since there exist Quick Setting Tiles for Developer Options (which includes Wireless Debugging) and long press of one brings you to it's related page in Settings, I thought to figure out what intent it is sending and how to replicate it.

## Observations

I started with searching for the source file responsible for the UI of the Developer Options page in Settings. I found `DevelopmentSettingsDashboardFragment.java` which has the method `handleQsTileLongPressActionIfAny`. In this method I saw that it is looking for an intent with the `ACTION_QS_TILE_PREFERENCES` action and an `EXTRA_COMPONENT_NAME` extra that has a ComponentName matching the Settings package name (`getPackageName()` = `com.android.settings`) and tile subclass name (`DevelopmentTiles.WirelessDebugging.class.getName()` = `com.android.settings.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$WirelessDebugging`, see `DevelopmentTiles.java`).

## Example (Code)

From these observations, I wrote the following example code:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(TileService.ACTION_QS_TILE_PREFERENCES);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_COMPONENT_NAME, new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.development.qstile.DevelopmentTiles$WirelessDebugging"));
try {
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}
```

## Testing Example (Images)

After testing it, it works perfectly. The Quick Settings Tile for Wirless Debugging doesn't even have to be enabled for it to work (though Developer Options does have to be enabled).

*Tested on Android 13 (Google Pixel 7 Pro).*

- Home shortcut of test app with example code

[image: Home shortcut of test app with example code]

- App launched, wireless debugging settings page shown

[image: App launched, wireless debugging settings page shown]

- In recent app list, it is shown to be running as a subactivity within the app

[image: In recent app list, it is shown to be running as a subactivity within the app]

Comment: It does not work. It shows an empty activity on Android 11.

Comment: @janelilep It seems there is no way to do this on Android 11. `handleQsTileLongPressActionIfAny` was added in Android 12. In the entire source for Android 11's Settings app there is no `SubSettingLauncher` with `WirelessDebuggingFragment.class` found, so an alternative solution is not possible. See: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/android12-release/src/com/android/settings/development/DevelopmentSettingsDashboardFragment.java#223

Answer (score 1):

i think no way to do that, this options for developers and you must enable it by yourself, not by codding