# How to open Wireless Debugging submenu in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-wifi-debugging

I am trying to build a shortcut to the Wireless Debugging screen and so far I have come to opening only up to the **Developer Options** submenu.

How do I open the **Wireless Debugging** screen from the code?
Refer the screenshot for the screen I am mentioning.[image]

Comment: Since its wireless debugging, I am trying this in only Android11+ devices.

Comment: There could be a way to get the intent when you are opening the settings via the shortcut. See logcat, there is `ActivityTastManager` that starts an settings intent, you just need to find a way to get those extras. `I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.SubSettings (has extras)} from uid 1000`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any way to go directly to the "Enable Usb Debugging" page in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55961409/any-way-to-go-directly-to-the-enable-usb-debugging-page-in-android)

Comment: I am currently working on 13+. So the OS itself has this QS tile which takes me directly to the said screen resulting in making this question Obsolete for me. But thankyou for the effort for answering. Hope it might be helpful for someone else how needs this and respond accordingly...

Answer (score 6):

Just use "Quick Settings Developer tiles"(in Settings -> "Developer options") to add "Wireless Debugging" shortcut to the "Quick Settings"

here is video about it -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gq1IVs0_ScY

Comment: This is not available on all phones.. eg Honor andorid 13..

Answer (score 2):

I Still don't know how to implement this in Android 12, but in 13, Android itself provides this Quick Setting. So just go to the Quick Settings, Tap on Edit, scroll down to bottom and search for "Wireless Debugging" settings and drag it wherever you need it.

Comment: On OnePlus phones with Android 13,  the quick setting tile does not open the Wireless debugging screen. It just toggles it on and off. Device manufacturers always mess things up.

Comment: @AmitJayant if you long press on the quick setting it will bring you to the full Wireless Debugging menu then you can click on Pair device with QR code or whatever you want, at least this works on my Pixel 7 Pro

Comment: @SamwiseGanges On OnePlus devices running Android 13, long press just closes the quick setting panel :(

Answer (score 1):

To add to the Quick Settings Developer Tiles solution, if you want to get to the actual Wireless Debugging menu rather than just turn it on and off, long press on the quick setting it will bring you there, then you can click on Pair device with QR code or whatever you want.